# how to return null value in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having two tables like `stock_inward`, `stock_outward`. I get this result by performing join operation like this.

Query:

```
SELECT i.number, i.material_code, i.price, i.quantity, i.date, o.number, o.quantity, o.date, o.type
FROM  `stock_outward` AS o
INNER JOIN  `stock_inward` AS i ON  `o`.material_code =  `i`.material_code
AND  `o`.material_code =  '1000002'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Result:

```
number  materialpricequantity   date    number  quantity    date    type
OPENING 1000002 75  50  2014-09-17  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
MRR/1-1 1000002 150 10  2014-09-17  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
MRR/1-2 1000002 100 50  2014-09-17  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
MRR/1-3 1000002 150 10  2014-09-18  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
MRR/1-4 1000002 10  10  2014-09-18  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
TRN/1-2 1000002 10  10  2014-09-18  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
```

My problem is that i want to show null where there is a  repeating the same number. my desired  o/p should be like this.

```
number  materialpricequantity   date    number  quantity    date    type
OPENING 1000002 75  50  2014-09-17  TRN/1-2 10  2014-09-18  Non-Returnable
MRR/1-1 1000002 150 10  2014-09-17   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL
MRR/1-2 1000002 100 50  2014-09-17   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL   
MRR/1-3 1000002 150 10  2014-09-18   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL   
MRR/1-4 1000002 10  10  2014-09-18   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL   
TRN/1-2 1000002 10  10  2014-09-18   NULL    NULL  NULL  NULL
```

is it posible to return null on repeating value in the columns.how to get the required output.sorry  there is lot of grammatical mistakes in my question.but i hope u people understand my intension.

Comment: This is not a good use of SQL. What are you using for presentation to the user e.g. php/html? It should be done by **"the presentation layer"** not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

While I have to agree putting this in your presentation logic makes the most sense, at times that might not be an option.  Since you're using MySql, you can take advantage of user defined variables:

```
SELECT i.number, i.material_code, i.price, i.quantity, i.date, 
  @number:=IF(@prevnumber=o.number,null,o.number) number,
  @quantity:=IF(@prevquantity=o.quantity,null,o.quantity) quantity,
  @date:=IF(@prevdate=o.date,null,o.date) date,
  @type:=IF(@prevtype=o.type,null,o.type) type,
  @prevnumber:=o.number, 
  @prevquantity:=o.quantity, 
  @prevdate:=o.date, 
  @prevtype:=o.type
FROM  `stock_outward` AS o
    INNER JOIN  `stock_inward` AS i ON  `o`.material_code =  `i`.material_code
        AND  `o`.material_code =  '1000002'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c447c6/4)